# how do I fix typescript error on try catch api call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, axios, try-catch

I am trying to figure out why I get a syntax error ion my code when trying to make an api call using Axios, async await and try catch. Error happens with the closing curly braces before the catch keyword. This error causes my code to compile with problems.

Error code is -->  **',' expected.ts(1005)**

```
const getProducts = async () =>{
    try{
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/products')
      .then((data) =>{
        console.log(data);
      }
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot `)` in your `.then()` callback function:

```
const getProducts = async () =>{
  try{
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/products')
      .then((data) =>{
        console.log(data);
      })
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are using async await ... .then() is redundant